# Firebase Hostingでデプロイしたファイルを確認したい

Tags: firebase

Firebase Hostingでサイトをデプロイした後で、

- 公開してはならないファイルをデプロイしていないかどうか確認したい
- 手元にあるプロジェクトファイルとデプロイ済みのファイルが一致するか確認したい

などの理由で、現在ホスティングされているファイルを確認したいことがあると思うのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか。
Hostingのダッシュボード画面を見ても、デプロイしたファイル数しか分からないように見えるのですが……

Answer (score 0, accepted):

確認する機能はないかと思います．
現状を再度デプロイしちゃうのが一番確実かと．
　
どうしても確認したいのであれば，ファイル数を数えるか，あるいは，
前もって `firebase deploy -m 'hogehoge'` でgitなどと合わせたコメントを入れておくと，ウェブコンソールからも確認できていいかもしれません．
　
また，公開してはならないファイルは，前もって除外を（ `firebase.json` で指定）しておきましょう．
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying#section-firebase-json

Comment: 私も同意見です。他にできることは、事前に`firebase serve`でローカルで確認することぐらいです。

Comment: 再デプロイがやはり確実なのですね。ありがとうございます。
ignore設定はきちんと書くよう心がけたいのですが、正しく書けているか不安なので、公開してはならないファイルをpublicディレクトリに入れるのは避けるようにします。
firebase deploy -m で gitと連携するというのは気付きませんでした。この件に限らずデプロイの管理に役に立ちそうです。